# asp.net mvc: disabled RoleManager is still executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web site where configured with:

```
<roleManager enabled='false'></roleManager>
```

But I still can see roleManager being executed in the pipeline (by looking at traces, also I am getting exception when roleManager tries to load roles from SQL providers configured in machine.config)

How can I disable roleManager?

Answer (score 4):

**fix**

add enableSimpleMembership with value false app setting to your web.config.

**cause**

```
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

will cause `Roles.Enabled` flag to be set to false, as expected,

but there is `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity` that says:

```
internal static void PreAppStartInit()
{
  if (!ConfigUtil.SimpleMembershipEnabled)
    return;
  ...
  Roles.Enabled = true;
  ...
}
```

this will override roleManager setting (this code is executed before RoleManager module is).

to disable `SimpleMembership` you can add app setting `enableSimpleMembership` with `value="false"` (web.config):

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <appSettings>
        <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

this will prevent webmatrix from enabling RoleManager.

Another solution (hack) is to remove RoleManager module from the list of modules:

```
....
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="RoleManager"/>
    </modules>
....
```

Comment: <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" /> saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

no... I don't think it's correct, even with enableSimpleMembership=false, you'd still need to implement a Dummy RoleProvider, otherwise, exception **"The Role Manager feature has not been enabled."**

Here's how to implement a dummy RoleProvider:

[Turning off only the Role Provider in SimpleMembership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760610/turning-off-only-the-role-provider-in-simplemembership/22393820#22393820)