# Turning off only the Role Provider in SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, simplemembership, roleprovider

I have read a ton of different posts and tutorials and couldn't find an answer to this specific need.

I'd like to use the `SimpleMembership` provider in my ASP.NET MVC app, but I would like to **turn the Role provider off** (OAuth too since I will not be using it). That means that I would like the SMP to create only `webpages_Membership` table on initialization, not the tables for oauth or roles.

**Note** that I don't want to turn off the SimpleMembership, **only the roles** and the oauth support.

**Question:** Can such a scenario be achieved by configuration?

**Attempt:**
I've tried by setting this in `web.config` (each where it belongs):

```
< add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />

< roleManager enabled="false" >
```

but then the `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` breaks on `LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized` with:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
| 
└> The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized
   |
   └> The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
```

which is completely true, but that's exactly what I want. Is there some way to tell the SimpleMembership not to use the Role Provider at all, while still retaining other features of WebSecurity's such as login other membership stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simple Membership API is not a loosely coupled architecture so it all comes in the WebSecurity assembly.The role manager will be instantiated lazily and the option of using it or not completely lies with you. As long as you're not using UserInRole methods, the role provider is not instantiated. In effect there is no loss in performance.
Thus you can just go ahead and use Simple Membership without using the role provider without worrying about turning it off.

Comment: But how do I prevent it from creating the tables in the database? The only way I know (did it on another project) was to create a custom role provider. In that case, the tables were not created.

Answer (score 0):

Here, a dummy role provider:

public class DummyRoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
    {
        private string _ApplicationName = null;

```
    public DummyRoleProvider ()
    {
        return;
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ApplicationName;
        }
        set
        {
            _ApplicationName = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);
    }

    public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }

    public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
    {
        throw new Exception("NOT IMPLEMENTED");
    }
}
```